# Django admin shows models name with extra "s" at the end

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm new to Django. In the admin panel, the name of the models has an extra "s" at the end. How can I fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Why is django-admin adding an 's'

There is a naming convention in Django the models are named in the singular. So your classes should be named:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
   ...

class Note(models.Model):
   ...
```

An instance of such a class represents a single comment, not a set of comments. Likewise consider the following

```
# doesn't really make sense
Comments.objects.get(...)

# reads much better
Comment.objects.get(...) #e.g. get from the comment objects
```

This is so much of a convention that Django admin expects for your classes to be named in the singular. For this reason, Django adds on an 's' as a standard way of pluralising your class names. (This will admittedly not work for all words and is very anglo-centric, but as an override, Django provides the `verbose_name_plural` meta-attribute).

#### How to fix it:

Rename your classes so they are in the singular. This will make your code a lot more readable to anyone who is used to reading django. It will also make your models named in a way consistent with other third-party packages. If your class names are not in English, or do not pluralise simply by appending an s, use `verbose_name_plural` e.g:

```
Class Cactus(models.Model):
    class Meta:  
        verbose_name_plural = 'Cacti'
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped.

Answer (score 6):

Add a meta class to your model and set `verbose_name_plural` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#verbose-name-plural). Ideally name your classes as singular (in this case you'd have `class Comment(models.Model)`.

```
class Comments(models.Model):


    class Meta:
        
        verbose_name_plural = 'Comments'
```

Good read:
[https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2018/02/10/django-tip-22-designing-better-models.html#:~:text=Always%20name%20your%20models%20using,not%20a%20collection%20of%20companies](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2018/02/10/django-tip-22-designing-better-models.html#:%7E:text=Always%20name%20your%20models%20using,not%20a%20collection%20of%20companies).

Comment: Thank you for your help.